# How i can earn variable from string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, function, variables

I have a `$string = "domain.com/path?query=test";`

I need to get of it 2 variables: `"domain.com" and "path?query=test"`

And then i need transform this variables to looks like this `"domain.com/api/path-2?query=test-2"`

How must this code looks likes? And it means i need to use `function`?

Thanks you!

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Currently, this question is too broad. Not to be mean, but the question if you need to use `function` tells me that you probably should go through a bunch of PHP 101 (the basics) tutorials first.

Comment: Thanks you! Yes , i am a beginner, so trying to learn everyting!

Comment: what do you mean by earn? also the domain is `.ou` not `.com`

Comment: I mean get, sorry....edit it. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for what you are trying to achieve

```
    $string = "domain.ou/path?query=test"; 
    $str_arr_domain = explode ("/", $string);
    $str_arr_params = explode ("?", $string);
    
    
    $newpath = "/api/path2/";
    
    $final_url = $str_arr_domain[0].$newpath.$str_arr_params[1];
    
    
    print_r($final_url);
```

Comment: Please don't answer "gimme-code"-type questions where there's no evidence that they made any effort at all. That will just reduce this site to a free code writing service since they will keep asking off-topic questions like this.

Comment: It's also unlikely that OP didn't have a full URL to begin with. [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) would be more apt for such cases than crude `explode` danceathons. Workarounds don't often benefit questions that are probably lacking in detail.